# Adding table to database requires site reload, why?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a database for an application and the database creates fine, however, I'm also telling the script to create and add a table to the database, but it makes me refresh the page before it adds the table to the DB. It will occasionally add it without me having to refresh the page (on initial load). Has anyone else had this problem? If so, how did you fix it? Here is my code:

```
<?php
$db_name = "815574_pay";
$db_user = "815574_pay99";
$db_pwd = "3Q87v8aL4t76213";
$tbl_name = "accounts";
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", $db_user, $db_pwd);
$db_create = "CREATE DATABASE " .$db_name;
$use_db = @mysql_select_db($db_name, $connect);
$tbl_create = "CREATE TABLE accounts(id INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), fName CHAR(25) NOT NULL, lName CHAR(50) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(50), password VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, card INT(16) NOT NULL, ccv INT(4) NOT NULL)";

function db_connect(){
    global $db_name;
    global $db_user;
    global $db_pwd;
    global $connect;

    if(mysql_connect() == TRUE){
    #Make sure the database has connected.
        echo "You are connected.<br>
        Welcome user $db_user <br>";
    }
    else{
    #Error checking for failed connection.
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " .mysql_connect_error();
    }
}
db_connect();

function db_create(){
    global $db_name;
    global $db_user;
    global $db_pwd;
    global $connect;
    global $db_create;

    if(mysql_query($db_create, $connect) == TRUE){
    #Make sure the database was created
        echo "Database $db_name was created.<br>";
    }
    else{
    #Error checking for failed database creation
        echo "Error creating database:  " .mysql_error() ."<br>";
    }
}
db_create();

function tbl_create(){
    global $db_name;
    global $db_user;
    global $db_pwd;
    global $connect;
    global $tbl_create;
    global $use_db;
    global $tbl_name;

    if($use_db == TRUE){
        mysql_query($tbl_create, $connect);
    #Make sure the table was successfully added
        echo "The table $tbl_name was added to $db_name.";
    }
    else{
    #Error checking for failed table creation
        echo "The table could not be added:  " .mysql_error();
    }
}
tbl_create();
mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `mysql_select_db` before `db_create`. Obviously, if the database does not exist, then you can't select it. Try moving the call to `mysql_select_db` after the call to `db_create` and handling any errors `mysql_select_db` might have.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see where you're referring to.  The mysql_select_db isn't called until the tbl_create function

Comment: Nevermind, I saw what you were talking about.  Thank you for the help.